# How to sort ANY list in Python 2.7 in DESCENDING order?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I think the title speaks enough for the question....

This is how i tried to do it:

```
r=input("rows")
c=input("colomns")
b=[]
for x in range(r):
    b.append(["O"] * c)

for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        b[i][j]=input("enter ")
```

Now this can be any matrix or a nested list.....
But if i use the SORTED fuction then i get the descending order of the lists in the main list....
for example-

```
list=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4].[4,5,6]]
```

and if i do sorted(list,reverse=True)

I get [[4,5,6],[2,3,4],[1,2,3] instead of [[6,5,4],[4,3,2],[3,2,1]]

I think we have to loop somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort the sublists, too.

```
>>> lst = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [4,5,6]]
>>> sorted([sorted(sublst, reverse=True) for sublst in lst], reverse=True)
[[6, 5, 4], [4, 3, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```